# Enforce fully qualified table name in Slick Query

Tags: scala, slick

How to enforce slick to add schema name in generated query so that it works with different db users.

I have two users one have all privileges while other is read only. I have granted select on user 1's tables to user 2.

But, on running query in Slick, encountered error ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Table allows to pass schema name as given below

```
         abstract class Table[T](_tableTag: Tag, _schemaName: Option[String], _tableName: String)
```

Example

```
            class InstrumentType(tag: Tag) extends 
                Table[String](tag,Some(SCHEMA_NAME), TableName)
```